# Ionic2 virtual scroll no prodiver for content

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I am trying to make a simple virtual scroll work.

Here's the view:

```
 <ion-list [virtualScroll]="items">
<ion-item-sliding *virtualItem="let item">
  <ion-item>
    <h2>{{ item.a }}</h2>
    <p>{{ item.b }}</p>
  <button item-right>View</button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="left">
    <button danger>
      <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button secondary>
      <ion-icon name="ios-build-outline"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
 </ion-list>
```

and the component:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {

    items: any[] = [];

    constructor() {

        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            this.items.push({ a: 1, b: 2 });
        }

    }
}
```

which produce the following exception:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html:8:2
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Content!
```

As if I had to have a provider for the virtual scrolling. There is nothing in the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) that suggests that I do need a provider.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare the variable for each `ion-item-sliding`. So it should be like this:

```
<ion-content>    
   <ion-list [virtualScroll]="items">
      <ion-item-sliding *virtualItem="let item">
        <ion-item>
          <h2>{{ item.a }}</h2>
          <p>{{ item.b }}</p>
        <button item-right>View</button>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="left">
          <button danger>
            <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <button secondary>
            <ion-icon name="ios-build-outline"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please notice `*virtualItem="let item"` in the `ion-item-sliding` element. That way you create a `item` variable for each element from the `items` array and then you can access its properties (`item.a` or `item.b`);

Comment: That's a typo :(. My bad... I've edited the code. The error is ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Content! with or without the *virtualItem="let item" btw.

Comment: I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkBmE6leKWvmA1pYzltL?p=preview) with your code (exactly like it's on your post) and it's not throwing the exception... Which version of Ionic2 are you using? The plunker uses `2.0.0-beta.9`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your plunker. The thing that was missing was : <ion-content></ion-content> in template. Adding it resolved the error... I proposed an edit on your code to have these tags.

Comment: @Mathieu Nls - thanks for pointing that out! that fixed this problem for me and a bug I was having with tabs too!